# Extracting all data summation on a specific time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model x, each record has an integer value y.

I need to find a list of summed y values from a specific date on a time interval till another specific date.

for example, the returned list should contain the summed y values of each month.

I also need to specify the starting date of the month.

If the record are as the following:-

1. {y:3,date:"23/Aug"}
2. {y:4,date:"1/Sep"}
3. {y:5,date:"17/Sep"}
4. {y:6,date:"1/Oct"}
5. {y:5,date:"5/Oct"}

And my starting date is 4th of August, the result should be as following:-
{7,11,5}

I have used this for grouping but I need to specify the beginning of the month instead of being its own default

x.group("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)") 
In other words, I need to define my 30 start and end dates.

Comment: Do u want the sum of integer value y for the specified date range? Or can you explain in a much better way?

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

can you please use the below code to select that date(to select the beginning of the month,

```
date = input_date
input_date.at_beginning_of_month()
```

This will return the date for the beginning of that month, which you have passed in as a input.

If you still want details please put in comments, because I still did get the explanation clear.